# cURL - script sending multiple unwanted requests

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP script that uses cURL to send an XML payload to an SMS service provider.  The problem is that users are complaining that they are receiving multiple SMS' (like sometimes 50 throughout the day) and I don't know if it's a problem with my code or with the SMS service provider.  The form that submits this is only accessible by someone who won't press submit more than once.

This is my code and I would be very grateful if someone could have a quick look over it to see if I am missing an important option that, if missing, will send multiple requests:

```
<?php
// the following code is only executed if there is no sms timestamp in the db for the user.  sms timestamp is added to the db when $error != true;
$error = false;

define('XML_PAYLOAD', '<xml data...>');
define('XML_POST_URL', 'https://URLOFSERVICEPROVIDER');

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, XML_PAYLOAD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen(XML_PAYLOAD) ));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
    $error = true;
} else {
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    switch($returnCode){
        case 200:
            break;
        default:
            $error = true;
            break;
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
if($error == false){
    // store that SMS was sent successfully
}
?>
```

Comment: I think your timeout is very low. You can check it by increasing to at least 30 Seconds as some time the process takes the time in computing uploading validation and many more things

Comment: I do not see any checks in your code where you check whether or not the SMS has been send already or not. Users might just press the send button multiple time because they are impatient.

Comment: @hakre sorry, I do check, but didn't add the coding. When `$error` is false, I store the timestamp in the db.  The code I posted is only executed if no timestamp is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i see, there is no code, that will do request twice.

Just one question - i dont see curl_exec in your code, is it ok ?

What about sending twice - try to add logs here

```
if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
    $error = true;
}
```

and here

```
if($error == false){
    // store that SMS was sent successfully
}
```

which will include current time, it will help you to see, how many times we walt into this part of script.